How FIML handles missing data
As title states, I have a question about how FIML (full information maximum likelihood) handles missing data. My understanding is that FIML only extends to missing outcomes and has limited ability to deal with missing predictors.

Am I correct to say that if there is complete data in the predictors and missing data in the outcomes, FIML retains all cases and produces unbiased estimates based on the full information that is available?
Am I correct to say that if there is missing data in the predictors and complete data in the outcomes, FIML drops all cases with missing predictors, and produces estimates that may be biased depending on the magnitude of missingness in the predictors?

Let’s say for example I want to use child care arrangements (categorical) as a predictor of literacy outcomes (continuous). Missingness is primarily an issue in the child care arrangements data (20% missingness). In this scenario, would using FIML (either in lavaan SEM or lme4 GLMM) “solve” the problem of missingness and produce unbiased estimates despite the high % of missingness in child care arrangements? Or would multiple imputation be necessary for high % of missingness in predictors?
Thank you very much for your time!
